# trimming output of script

Tags: shell, sed, trim, output

```
ping website.com -n 3 | grep Minimum
```

Will show you

```
Minimum = 24ms, Maximum = 62ms, Average = 36ms
```

What do I add to trim everything except the Minimum ping? To only make it output "24" ?

Comment: Or, `ping ... -n 3` will show a usage error if `ping` does not accept `-n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pipe the output of `ping` into `sed`:

```
sed 's/Minimum = \([0-9]\+\)ms.*/\1/'
```

Or if you have `GNU grep`, pipe into:

```
grep -oP "(?<=Minimum = )[0-9]+(?=ms)"
```

Comment: ping website.com -n 3 | grep Minimum | sed 's/Minimum = \([0-9]\+\)ms.*/\1/'

Like that?

Comment: @Aaron: `sed` can do pattern matching. I mean like this: `ping website.com -n 3 | sed 's/Minimum = \([0-9]\+\)ms.*/\1/'`. HTH.

Comment: the grep one does more what I want. I just want it to return the value of the Minimum ping, so just a number. But yes thanks.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure why the `sed` isn't working for you. Perhaps you have leading whitespace. If so, try: `sed 's/.*Minimum = \([0-9]\+\)ms.*/\1/'`